# Difference between two similar tcpdump filters

Tags: tcp, udp, ip, tcpdump, packet-sniffers

I don't understand the difference between these two filters found [here](http://www.wains.be/pub/networking/tcpdump_advanced_filters.txt):

```
proto[x:y] & z = z  : every bits are set to z when applying mask z to proto[x:y]
proto[x:y] = z      : p[x:y] has exactly the bits set to z
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With that syntax you can filter the packets bitwise.

For example, consider the first two bytes of an IP frame.

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
|Version|  IHL  |Type of Service|          Total Length         |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

Let's say you want to filter only ip packets with version equal to 4 (indicating IPv4 packets).

You can do something like this

```
tcpdump -i ethX 'ip[0:1] & 0xf0 = 0x40'
```

- **ip[0:1]** means "extract 1 bytes from offset zero of the IP frame"
- **& 0xf0** filters out the IHL bits off the first byte
- **= 0x40** will match only if the version bits contains the number 4

et voilà, you built a custom filter digging deeply into the captured frames.

In the two cases you listed, i suppose there's a typo.

I think it should be:

```
proto[x:y] & z = n   : every bits are set to n when applying mask z to proto[x:y]
proto[x:y] = n       : p[x:y] has exactly the bits set to n
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It's all clear now.  It was `proto[x:y] & z = z` that put me off track. :)